# How to make sense of the side jump mechanism for anomalous Hall effect?

Tags: ferromagnetism, hall-effect

According to this paper, https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.2.4559, the electron (wave packet), moving along $x$ axis, undergoes a transverse shift $Δy$ after collision with spin-orbit coupling center. How to make sense of this?

I can understand a continuous transverse drift due to SOC (skew scattering) as an effective field gradient which force the spin gradually to one direction. However,  the side jump, an almost instantaneous shift, confuses me.

Comment: My question can be rephrased as: Why does the center of wave packet shift due to SOC according to side jump?